# Validating with php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to validate my user server side with php and its saying I'm getting an Fatal error: Call to undefined function reGenPassHash() in /home/xtremer/public_html/kowmanager/application/models/loggedin.php on line 13 now I have the model that includes the reGenPassHash function auto loaded so I thought it'd be available to use but for some reason its not because of this message. Someone explain why?

Model:

```
public function check_login($username, $password)
{
    $generated_password = reGenPassHash($password);
    $query = "SELECT user_id WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
    $result = $this->db->query($query, array($username, $generated_password));

    if ($result->num_rows == 1)
    {
        return $result->row(0)->user_id;

    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Usermanagement extends CI_Controller { 

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}   

public function index()
{
    //Config Defaults Start
    $msgBoxMsgs = array();//msgType = dl, info, warn, note, msg
    $cssPageAddons = '';//If you have extra CSS for this view append it here
    $jsPageAddons = '';//If you have extra JS for this view append it here
    $metaAddons = '';//Sometimes there is a need for additional Meta Data such in the case of Facebook addon's
    $siteTitle = '';//alter only if you need something other than the default for this view.
    //Config Defaults Start


    //examples of how to use the message box system (css not included).
    //$msgBoxMsgs[] = array('msgType' => 'dl', 'theMsg' => 'This is a Blank Message Box...');

    /**********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, Start*/

    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        $bodyContent = "login";//which view file
    }
    else
    {
        $bodyContent = "cpanel/index";//which view file
    }

    $bodyType = "full";//type of template

    /***********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, End*/

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, Start.
    //If msgBoxMsgs array has anything in it, if so displays it in view, else does nothing.      
    if(count($msgBoxMsgs) !== 0)
    {
        $msgBoxes = $this->msgboxes->buildMsgBoxesOutput(array('display' => 'show', 'msgs' =>$msgBoxMsgs));
    }
    else
    {
        $msgBoxes = array('display' => 'none');
    }

    if($siteTitle == '')
    {
        $siteTitle = $this->metatags->SiteTitle(); //reads 
    }

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, End.

    $this->data['msgBoxes'] = $msgBoxes;
    $this->data['cssPageAddons'] = $cssPageAddons;//if there is any additional CSS to add from above Variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['jsPageAddons'] = $jsPageAddons;//if there is any addictional JS to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['metaAddons'] = $metaAddons;//if there is any addictional meta data to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['pageMetaTags'] = $this->metatags->MetaTags();//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['siteTitle'] = $siteTitle;//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['bodyType'] = $bodyType;
    $this->data['bodyContent'] = $bodyContent;
    $this->load->view('usermanagement/index', $this->data);
}

function login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|max_length[12]|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->index();
    }
    else
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $user_id = $this->loggedin->check_login($username, $password);

        if(! $user_id)
        {
           redirect('/'); 
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                'logged_in' => TRUE,
                'user_id' => $user_id
            ));
            redirect('cpanel/index');
        }
    }
}

function logout()
{
   $this->session->sess_destroy();
   $this->index();
}       

}

/* End of file usermanagement.php */ 
/* Location: ./application/controllers/usermanagement.php */
```

**EDIT :**

I'm trying to make sure my logic is correct. Should I be working with the regenPassHash function call in my controller instead?

**EDIT 2 :**

This is an example of how my password functions look (getfunc model):

```
<?php
function GenPassHash($logPass)
{
    $usersalt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 11);
    $encPass = sha1($logPass);
    $sltPass = $encPass . $usersalt;$encSPass = sha1($sltPass);
    $passArray = array($encSPass,$usersalt);
    return $passArray;
}
function reGenPassHash($postDpass, $storeSalt)
{
    $logPass = $postDpass;
    $encPass = sha1($logPass);
    $sltPass = $encPass . $storeSalt;
    $encSPass = sha1($sltPass);
    return $encSPass;
}

//useage
$logPass = "catcher05";//this could be your posted variable from registration

$passforDB = GenPassHash($logPass);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($passforDB);
echo "</pre>";
echo "Encrypted Password: " . $passforDB[0] . "<br />";
echo "Salted Value: " . $passforDB[1] . "<br />";

echo "----------------------------------<br />";
//in this example I post $passforDB[1] with the below function to stimulate having pulled it from a DB
echo reGenPassHash($logPass, $passforDB[1]); //you would query based on your username being posted and only pull the salt and encrypted pass you would use the salt in this function

?>
```

Controller:

```
function login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|max_length[12]|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->index();
    }
    else
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $generated_password = $this->getfunc->reGenPassHash($password);

        $user_id = $this->loggedin->check_login($username, $password);

        if(! $user_id)
        {
           redirect('/'); 
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                'logged_in' => TRUE,
                'user_id' => $user_id
            ));
            redirect('cpanel/index');
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function check_login($username, $password)
{
$query = "SELECT * WHERE username = ".$username."";
$result = $this->db->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows == 1)
{
    $passwordDB = $result->row(0)->password;
    $passwordDB2 = $result->row(0)->password2;


    return $result->row(0)->user_id;

}
else
{
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of the model where the reGenPassHash() function is? Are you definitely including that file ABOVE the check_login function?

Comment: If its autoloaded wouldn't that mean that its included above this model.

Answer (score 3):

reGenPassHash() function is not visible to the check_login() method. call the reGenPassHas with the object.

ex: `$object->reGenPassHas()`.

this is a scope issue

Comment: Yes, Best practice to have `reGenPassHas()` in controlloer as it is not playing with your database. if your methods going to working with DB, best practice is to move them to the model.

[Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Answer (score 1):

Autoloading is only going to kick in for object methods. You're not using object notation on your call to the regen function, so it's being treated like a regular function call - and this function is not defined.

Comment: Can I call a function from anther model inside of this model?

Comment: So your saying it should be $generated_password = $this->model->getfunc->reGenPassHash($password); instead of   $generated_password = reGenPassHash($password);

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your reGenPassHash function through your model object like:

```
$this->your_model_with_pass_function->reGenPassHash()
```

Comment: Your code should work as you have edited it now, but as other posts said you should move your password functions into your model or else into a library if you need more than one controller to have access to the functions. Really your model is a library. Just move it to libraries and autoload it as a library and you will call it the same way as your new code shows. Is it still not working?

Answer (score 1):

The only error i saw with your code, is that you **are calling your method the wrong way**. For any class method, you need a objects to access the methods.

This might $this. in your case or something else in other cases.

Try using `$this -> reGenPassHash()` to call the method **only if it relies with in the model,** or you will need respective object modifier.

**UPDATE:**

1. Include your GenPassHash() & reGenPassHash() on your controller.
2. Instead of `$this->getfunc->reGenPassHash()` use `$this->reGenPassHash()`

Comment: Yes, logically, your model should contain your database related logic only. .... The function reGenPassHash() is related on developing a hashed code only, independent of the database... so the code should be placed in controller instead :)

Comment: I think I'm still stuck on this because how I should be achieving my goal. I'm going to update my post again with some updated stuff and see if it makes sense to you.